# Count If with a number of criteria and to only count unique

Tags: excel, google-sheets, unique, formula

I'm having great difficulty adapting a formula to only count unique values in Google Sheets. I'm hoping someone can help.

What I need is to know how many unique text entries there are in the column '$AC:$AC' where:

```
$AA:$AA = "DG"
$AL:$AL = "Booked"
$AM:$AM = the cell I2
```

I currently have this formula but think it probably needs to be complexly re-written as a query to include the only count the unique values part

```
=COUNTIFS($AL:$AL,"No",$AA:$AA,"DG",$AM:$AM,I2)
```

To be clear, if there are 6 entries that meet the criteria but all have the same entry in the column $AC:$AC, it should only count once.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to count how many difference entries in AC that meet the criteria you gave.

By this logic, it's best if you first select out a list of matching entries, and make them unique : 
`=UNIQUE(QUERY(AA:AM,"Select AC where AA = 'DG' and AL = 'Booked' and AM = '" & I2 & "'"))`

Then just count the number of unique entry appear: 
`=COUNTIF(UNIQUE(QUERY(AA:AM,"Select AC where AA = 'DG' and AL = 'Booked' and AM = '" & I2 & "'")),"<>")`